# PayFlow Recurring Payments Refund

Tags: paypal, recurring, payflowpro, payflowlink

Is it possible to make a refund via PayPal PayFlow API on last transaction when I'm using PayFlow recurring payments.
Thanks,
Maciek

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer to this is "yes".

You need to credit as you would a normal transaction. Parameters are:

```
USER
VENDOR
PARTNER
PWD
TENDER=C // C = credit card, P = PayPal
TRXTYPE=C //  S = Sale transaction, A = Authorisation, C = Credit, D = Delayed Capture,
ORIGID=XXXX // ORIGID to the PNREF value returned from the original transaction
```

Then you may need to cancel the recurring transaction to stop it happening again. Parameters are:

```
USER
VENDOR
PARTNER
PWD
ACTION=C // C = Cancel
TRXTYPE=R //  R = Recurring
ORIGPROFILEID=XXXX // Original Profile ID (of the recurring transaction)
```

https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_recurringbilling_guide.pdf

Comment: Hi @roobie , when i tried above code , it give me this response, did you faced the same issue?? array:3 [▼
  "RESULT" => "25"
  "PNREF" => "R105AA8EAF86"
  "RESPMSG" => "Not signed up for this tender type"
]

Comment: No, but I'm guessing you've used "TENDER=C" when you're not set up for Credit Cards - should that be P? But if that's not it, and google can't help, just raise another question!